# Mercurial on 'plain' webhosting

Tags: version-control, mercurial, ftp

I have been using mercurial now for a while for all my website projects. I mainly use a central repository (Bitbucket) and clone projects to my local dev-box whenever needed.
From my development environment I always use (S)FTP to upload the website or changes to the live server.
But since most live websites change (uploaded files, ini-files, other developers, etc.) over time I would like to place the live site under version control as well. Unfortunatly most of my clients use (cheap) plain old webhosting with only FTP access (SFTP if I am lucky).
I have been reading:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StaticHTTP

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

and some of the results Google threw at me. I somehow feel I am completely misunderstanding all this and fail to come up with a good workflow.
What would be a good workflow for this case and how would I set that up? I would not mind changing to, for example, Bazaar or Git if needed (I am a bit afraid of Git to be honest, everything I read about Git seems 10x more technical than anything I read about Mercurial or Bazaar, and installing it on Windows seems to imply installing all sorts of secondary software it seems, but that is another matter. I am only mentioning it to indicate Git is a last resort for me)

Comment: Are we talking about publishing the contents of your website to the hosting server? You dont't need Mercurial for this.

Comment: First of all, there seems to be an increasing tendency to prefer version control over ftp, which I understand.
Secondly, we I am mainly talking about keeping track of changes on the live server.

Comment: The articles you listed are talking about publishing the repository over http, which is likely at odds with publishing the actual site from that location.

Comment: You know, the thing is, people talk about how outdated and insecure ftp is and how wonderfull version control. On paper I agree. But in practice, when it come to building and *maintaining* websites, version control seems to need at least a VPS to create a good workflow. Unfrotunatly most of my clients have very basic needs and small budgets. Comparing a stabndard webhosting account of 6 euro per year to a basic VPS for 100 euro a year is a very simple desicion to make. Cheap webhosting is a very common denominator, why does no version control take that into account?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I decided the best way to do this for now (until I can come up with a better solution) is to sync the ftp folder with a local folder (using third party software like e.g. goodsync). That way I can treat the website as if it is a (second) local repository.
So my workflow now is:

1. Create repository on locally synced live-site
2. Clone to development folder
3. push/update changes between development & live synced folders
4. Once development is done, an automated script will commit & push
   changes on live synced folder to bitbucket.

If anyone can think of a better way to do this I am all ears ;-)

Comment: After 3 days of playing with this setup I decided it just does not work. Keeping the remote server in sync with my local machine is both too slow and too much of a resource hog. Basiclaly I am reverting to my old setup where I run a daily backup on the live server which is mailed to me, which I then have to manually copy over my local repository. One would think that by now a good alternative to keeping websites up to date had been invented?